# Grails oauth plugin doesn't work

Tags: grails, oauth

I tried to use oauth plugin 2.6.1 on a Grails 2.4.4 blank application.
I followed instruction on documentation for quickstart, however when I start the application I have that stacktrace:

```
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllerTagLibraryApi': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllerTagLibraryApi.setTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.exception.InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllerTagLibraryApi': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllerTagLibraryApi.setTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.exception.InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllerTagLibraryApi.setTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.exception.InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.exception.InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.exception.InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.exception.InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvalidOauthProviderException: [:] configured as an API for facebook does not appear to be a valid Class. It should be a class extending from the org.scribe.builder.Api class
->>   48 | afterPropertiesSet in uk.co.desirableobjects.oauth.scribe.OauthService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

The error seems quite clear, but I don't understand if it's a configuration problem.

This is my configuraton in Config.groovy:

```
oauth {
    providers {
        twitter {
            api = TwitterApi
            key = 'my-key'
            secret = 'my-secret'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you dont have configuration block for facebook inside your config.groovy ? Make sure you have imported the class FacebookApi in your config.groovy

Comment: Ok, it was an import issue :)
Thanks Burt

Comment: Added my comment as answer, you can accept it

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have imported the class FacebookApi in your Config.groovy